# Using TextResponse in Scrapy spider

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have a basic scrapy spider dealing with XML pages:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = [
        "website.com",
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css("item"):
            yield {...}
```

I realized it wasn't working properly because the responses are binary encoded. I discovered the scrapy [TextResponse](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=binary#textresponse-objects) object, which is a subclass of Response that can handle binary data. I am unsure how to integrate it into my scraper. My current solution is to override the response object inside the parse function, like this:

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = [
        "website.com",
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        # --- override response object with TextResponse ---
        response = TextResponse(response.url, body=response.body, encoding="utf-8")
        for item in response.css("item"):
            yield {...}
```

Is there a better way to get my spider to use TextResponse instead of the basic Response object?

Comment: This seems pretty clean to me, what exactly would you be looking for?

Comment: Why are you not getting a `TextResponse` from Scrapy in the first place? That’s usually what happens if the response can be decoded into text. It may be a bug in Scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

What I'll usually do is just:

```
def parse(self, response):
    data = response.body.decode('utf-8')
```